# Pipe password to prompt in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I am using a Python script to query data via an API which requires authentication. That script prompts the user for the input of a password (no other input required). I want to automate this workflow using the Windows Scheduler and thus need to automatically provide the password upon the prompt in `automate.bat` file.

However, the pipe is simply not recognized. I tried the following MWE:

`foo.py`

```
from getpass import getpass
password = getpass()
print(password)
```

`automate.bat`:

```
echo PWD | python foo.py
```

There is no difference to executing `python foo.py` directly; both times, I need to provide the password. The pipe works otherwise fine, e.g. tested by `echo 111 | (set /p readvalue= & set readvalue)`.

Working on Windows 10.

Thank you.

Comment: `echo PWD | ...` will actually pipe `PWD` + _space_ to the right-side command; better use `echo(PWD| ...` (yes, I know, this looks odd, but the `(` is the only safe way to echo arbitrary strings, even empty ones or such that begin with `/?`)...

Answer (score 1):

content of `foo.py`:

```
print(input())
```

calling it via:

```
echo "hello world" | python foo.py
```

You need `input()`

Comment: Thank you! However, I would not like the user input to be echoed, so this is a second-best solution. The reason is that the python script will be used despite the automation, so this feature is relevant. Is there no other solution?